# Multiple docker containers and scallinguUp with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, automation, docker-compose

When a new account is created in my app I need to launch a web site for this new user. I decided to use docker for this, so each new client get a brand new container running it's own website, each container has a environment variable with a virtual host/domain name. Combining this with a nginx reverse proxy everything works. On my local dev machine all I need to do is add the virtual host to my host file and I can access the newly created website.

To deploy this I can use a regular AWS EC2 instance, but since this is an automated process it'll eventually hit the cpu/memory limits.

I've also checked AWS EBS. But each environment gets it's own EC2 instance (assuming each new website = one new environment). If I choose the MultiContainer setup I'd have to ship new code to EBS every time I create a new account and this also means a few seconds to reboot/rebuild the environment.

How can I scale this up?

Answer (score 2):

If you decided to use AWS, how think about considering `AWS ECS` service. It is service of docker container optimizing with AWS EC2.

You can make a cluster be composed of EC2 instances. these instances are operated scalable. it is just require `task definition` what json formation of ECS.

Kubernetes, EKS are also good choice for container. But it should be necessary much learning curve.

> See :
>
> Here's [AWS ECS Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the full picture here, I would recommend you look at something like Kubernetes. Thinking mainly about the deployment and memory stuff you've mentioned above.

You could have multiple EC2 'nodes', Kubernetes will scale the containers (pods) across these nodes in the best way possible.

Deployment wise, you could look at Jenkins, Fabric: http://www.fabfile.org/ etc. Where it uses the kubectl cli to deploy for you. A lot of this could be automated and scaled rather easy. Let me know if you have any questions, but Amazon EKS is worth looking at.